# @reduxjs/toolkit error: node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/index"' has no exported member 'PayloadAction'

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I am trying to use the PayloadAction type in my react-native/expo/typescript project like so:

`import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';`

createSlice and createAsyncThunk work fine but PayloadAction gives my the following error:

[ts] Module '"/Users/tim/Documents/Projects/app fullstack/my-app/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/index"' has no exported member 'PayloadAction'.

I checked the index file of the redux toolkit library and I notice that typescript doesn't like exports with the type keyword such as:

`export type { PayloadAction, PayloadActionCreator, ActionCreatorWithNonInferrablePayload, ActionCreatorWithOptionalPayload, ActionCreatorWithPayload, ActionCreatorWithoutPayload, ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload, PrepareAction, } from './createAction';`

but is ok with export without the types keyword such as:

`export { createSlice, buildCreateSlice, asyncThunkCreator, ReducerType, } from './createSlice';`

edit:
Here is my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx expo start --port 8084",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "ts:check": "tsc"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "expo": "~50.0.2",
    "expo-asset": "~9.0.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~16.0.6",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.3",
    "expo-sqlite": "~13.2.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.20",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/sqlite3": "^3.1.11",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~50.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: What *specific* version of Redux-Toolkit are you using, e.g. what version is *installed*?

Comment: I am using Redux-Toolkit 2.2.1

Comment: Is that just what you have specified in your package.json file? Is that what is ***installed*** in the project? You can check with `npm list @reduxjs/toolkit`. Maybe try deleting the entire `node_modules` directory and re-run `npm install` to re-install the project dependencies according to your package.json file.

Comment: That is what I have in my package.json file. I ran "npm list @reduxjs/toolkit" and it says the same thing "@reduxjs/toolkit@2.2.1". I tried reinstalling my dependancies and I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you [edit] to share your package.json file, and any other relevant details about your environment you think may be helpful?

Comment: I added my package.json file as an edit to my post. I am working on building an expo react-native app. I am using node version 17.9.1 which is the latest version compatible with MacOs High Sierra. Thank you, I appreciate your help.